# Xamarin.ios does NOT work on real iOS device but it works on Simulator

Tags: c#, ios, web-services, xamarin.ios, rest

I build a mobile App. This App is working really well on iOS simulator, Android emulator and Android real device. But When I published it on TestFlight and install on a real iOS device then this app does not work. I don't get any error. My spinner(activator indicator) is running forever and I cannot get any response from HttpResponse. I built this app with **Web service.** Therefore I'm using **http://46.221.....** url to **post or get** request. I thought that iOS does not support **http** request because of security . But if it's true then Why this app is running on simulator very well?  I couldn't find any solution.  Here is my part of codes:

```
public async Task<BSUser> ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        string url = Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Get(Constants.URL_KEY, "") + "/api/Validateuser";
        HttpClient _Client = new HttpClient();

        var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
          {"userName", userName},
          {"password", password}
        };

        string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await _Client.PostAsync(url, content);
            if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseData = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseData).ToString();
                UserInfo userInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(result);

                BSUser value = new BSUser();
                value.UserName = userInfo.userCode;

                return value;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (SystemException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3JF2.png)

Comment: Did you post to TestFlight `Release` build with `NSUrlSession` http client implementation?

Comment: Hi Alexey! I did't build it with **NSUrlSession** when I release it. But  I added 
' <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
         <true/>
 </dict>'

this to my info.plist
Could you give me some explanation about your suggest with an example?

Comment: All this settings will have no effect if default managed implementation of `HttpClient` is used, give `NSUrlSession` a try with this settings, maybe it will help.

Comment: I found what you said. And I released my App to TestFlight again with NSUrlSession but I have same error. When I try to log-in My app is crashing and going down. But iOS simulator still works fine. It's so interesting!

Comment: All I can recommend in this case is to improve your logging and error handling.

Comment: Thank you for your help my friend. I'll connect my iOS phone to Xamarin via usb cable and I'll set breakpoint to my service & client codes. I'll observe what happens one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem of my project. It's not related on HTTPS-HTTP or security situation. It's so absurd and illogical but it's the real problem. My app works on any iOS simulator well enough however, Minimum version of simulator is **iPhone-8** in Visual Studio. But When I installed my app on **real devices of iPhone-6** I got **Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException** error. But My HttpResponse returned **200OK** and I see all values which comes from my service as a json. I think there some difference between old ve new versions of iPhones to convert Json Serialization.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you really should take advantage of HTTPS instead of HTTP. You can refer to these pages for more information:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-handle-the-https-requirements-in-ios-with-app-transport-security

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/preventing_insecure_network_connections?language=objc

This is the problem with ATS in ios, if you want to use HTTP, you can config of it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/ats#configuring-ats-options.

Someone others meet the same problem like you:[Xamarin Forms, iOS will not open links in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59200529/xamarin-forms-ios-will-not-open-links-in-webview)

Comment: Hi Steven! Thank you for response. I know the advantages of https. I found my problem. it's related about iPhone versions. New versions of iPhone can convert my Json data but  in old versions of iPhone I should make some fix. Because already I get my all values from services.

Comment: @Veysel Turan, so it's not the problem of HTTP? And it's the ios version that caused this problem? just a little curious. and thanks for your response.

Comment: Yess!! I get my all data from service using HTTP, there is no problem with http request. My problem is device of iPhone-6. it gives me error to convert data to Json.Serialization. But surprisingly, my code works on all iOS simulators which are  iPhone 8 and higher. Additionally, I have no iPhone 8 or higher real device. Therefore I have no idea whether the problem will occur in these versions of real device as well or not.